# How to make GM_getValue existent in Greasemonkey on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey-4, firefox-quantum

I have this Greasemonkey demo script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         GM_getValue, GM_setValue don't work demo
// @version      0.2
// @author       You
// @include      /^https:\/\/stackoverflow.com/$/
// @grant        GM_getValue
// @grant        GM_setValue
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

console.log('script started');
var id = GM_getValue('testName', 0);
console.log('got ' + id);
id++;
GM_setValue('testName', id);
```

Calling this with the https://stackoverflow.com/, it is well visible that it is called.

However, I get this error on the console:

```
Script error:  
ReferenceError: GM_getValue is not defined
Stack trace:
userScript@user-script:demosrv/GM_getValue%2C%20GM_setValue%20don%27t%20work%20demo:372:5
scopeWrapper@user-script:demosrv/GM_getValue%2C%20GM_setValue%20don%27t%20work%20demo:381:9
@user-script:demosrv/GM_getValue%2C%20GM_setValue%20don%27t%20work%20demo:361:17
```

I've digged docs a lot, but it seems `GM_{get,set}Value` simply don't want to exist.

Why is it so? How to make it working?

I am using Firefox.

Comment: Extension from the future: I've recently tried *Tampermonkey*. It looks far better in all senses. It is compatible with Greasemonkey userscripts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`GM_getValue` and `GM_setValue` are now obsolete in the GreaseMonkey. The correct methods are `GM.setValue` and `GM.getValue`.

The GreaseMonkey documentation uses often the old API call names, which is a continuous error in it. Probably it wasn't correctly updated.

As the documentation [here](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.getValue) says, GM functions can run in different scopes. Unfortunately, I didn't find any info until now, which scopes are existing and how can we switch between them.

The old references manywhere on the net, using `GM_getValue` are all obsolete.

The important things:

- While `GM_getValue` were functions with a return value, `GM.getValue` and `GM.setValue` return `Promise`s.
- You can use them nearly as you used in the old, nice versions, using the `await` call.

This example on the remote link, works:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Greasemonkey set-and-get Example
// @description Stores and logs a counter of executions.
// @grant       GM.setValue
// @grant       GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==

(async () => {
  let count_before = await GM.getValue('count', 0);

  // Note awaiting the set -- required so the next get sees this set.
  await GM.setValue('count', count_before + 1);

  // Get the value again, just to demonstrate order-of-operations.
  let count_after = await GM.getValue('count');

  console.log('Greasemonkey set-and-get Example has run', count_after, 'times');
})();
```

However, there is still no more clear documentation about the scopes and how can we interact with them.

It seems, there are at least two scopes:

- In one of them, you can manipulate the DOM, but don't have access to the `GM.*` API.
- In another, you have access to the `GM.*` API (and thus, you can make script-local persistent storage), but don't have access to the DOM.
- Between the scopes, we can communicate through asychronous calls.
- Why would this trouble *increase* the security, probably not even the GM developer(s) could say.

Thus, the way to develop new GreaseMonkey scripts for 4.0, is to start with their example script and then follow an incremental trial & error path.

---

Extension: another trouble I've found: the existence of `await` in the script seems to make greasemonkey to ignore the whole script et al. In the example, it doesn't seem to happen, but in more complex scripts, it does. I didn't debug it too deeply - I simply ignore `await` and use the Promises on the old way (`GM.getValue("myValue").then(function(myValue) { ... });`). It makes the code more crappy, but so is it.

Comment: Yeap, I can't seem to reproduce their example in the documentation. The moment GreaseMonkey sees the `await` word in the script, it just doesn't execute the script. This is horrible.

Comment: @Sudhi Yeah. But, for example, the example works. As I tried to extend it, it suddenly stopped working on a point. I have no idea, why. Maybe this userscript ignorer feature of the GM is initiated by the existence of `await` and yet another thing - I don't know, exactly what.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't figure out either. I gave up, and decided to go back to 3.17 on FirefoxESR. Now `GM_getValue('foo', 'init');` returns `null` to me :-/

Comment: @Sudhi Promises are not so bad on second spot as for the first, and I don't like to downgrade. So I solved the problem with promises, but without await. I have no idea, what could make such a popular software so badly maintained.

Comment: Chiming in here to say thank you for confirming that the presence of `await` makes GreaseMonkey entirely ignore the script - I felt sure I must be missing something.